# Angularjs ng-style changes z-index of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to fade out an image the further a user scrolls on my page.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqkzdt34/2/) is a minimal example of the page.

The problem is: Somehow the Z-Index of the image which should be faded seems to change when the opacity value is applied by angularjs.
If you remove the ng-style tag, you see that the image is actually behind the fixed navbar.
But with the ng-style tag the image is on top of the navbar.

So instead of

```
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" 
        ng-class="{'header-img-text' : true}" ng-style="{opacity : headerTextOpacity}">
```

using

```
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" 
        ng-class="{'header-img-text' : true}">
```

gives the correct behaviour when it comes to layering. But the opacity does not wirk then (obviously).

Is there a way to prevent this? How is this done right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding z-index to nav-bar resolves the issue..

Comment: Duuh. Yeah. Most obvious solution. I was just so confused because I did not expect this change to have any influence on the ordering. Thanks